# Why is mysql connection not working with dotenv variables

Tags: sql, node.js, dotenv

Good evening,

I have been trying to connect to my database by using dotenv variables.
It worked perfectly before i used it.

I have 2files: 1 file mysqlConfig, where i put my settings for my database, and .env where i put my variables.

I don't see what i am doing wrong here:

```
SOCKET_PATH='/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock'
USER='root'
PASSWORD='root'
HOST='localhost'
DATABASE='Groupomania'
```

MysqlConfig :

```
require('dotenv').config();
var mysql = require('mysql');

// Connexion à MYSQL
var bdd = mysql.createConnection({
  socketPath : process.env.SOCKET_PATH,
  user : process.env.USER,
  password : process.env.PASSWORD,
  host : process.env.HOST,
  database : process.env.DATABASE
});

module.exports = bdd;
```

Thank you for your help

Have a nice evening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, i just found the issue...

I used console log for every varibales, util i figured out that my USER was not the correct one... it was my last name (i don't know why ?)

I did not know the variable USER is kind of reserved ?

Anyway, this way it works...

```
SOCKET_PATH='/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock'
USERDB='root'
PASSWORD='root'
HOST='127.0.0.1'
DATABASE='Groupomania'
```

mysqlConfig

```
require('dotenv').config();
var mysql = require('mysql');

// Connexion à MYSQL
var bdd = mysql.createConnection({
  socketPath : process.env.SOCKET_PATH,
  user : process.env.USERDB,
  password : process.env.PASSWORD,
  host : process.env.HOST,
  database : process.env.DATABASE
});

module.exports = bdd;
```

Your answer helped a lot, thanks !!

Comment: `process.env` means environment variables from your machine. Its a list and Nodejs always takes variable values from the system, if it does not exist then as a fallback looks into your .env file config. If you try to run `echo $USER` in your terminal it will print the same value u were experienced before (assuming you are on a linux machine). So that was a reason u did not get value from your .env file because it is already declared.

Answer (score 2):

It might be because the `dotenv` package hasn't been able to find your `.env` file.

try printing any of the variables, and see if it's undefined. If it is, my assumption is correct.

```
console.log(process.env['SOCKET_PATH'])
```

In that case, you need to manually specify the relative path to your .env file. That can be done by passing an options object to your config function, containing the property path:

```
const path = require('path')
require('dotenv').config({ 
   path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../.env') 
})
```